# Rich string with cell alignement formatting using xlsxwriter

Tags: xlsxwriter

I'm writing an HTML parser that generates an XLSX file from an HTML table. The table contains colored data such as:

```
<td>Some <mark color="red"><b>coloured, bolded</b></mark> text</td>
```

During parsing, I generate an array of tokens ready for passing to `write_rich_string` or `write_string` depending on how many strings are generated by the HTML parser.

There are quite a few cases where the HTML parser generates a array of 2 strings and a format, to be written to a cell, like:

```
['string 1', 'string2', format]
```

I cannot use `write_string` because there is more than 1 string. But I cannot use `write_rich_string` either, because `write_rich_string` pops the format and chokes on an array of 2 strings. Passing the following data to `write_rich_string` does not raise any issue, which feels strange in comparison:

```
['string1', 'string2', 'string3', format]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like you aren’t passing the correct parameters to the API. Can you add a small working example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I've rewritten the issue to provide additional information and latest results.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could have been to join `string1` and `string2`, and then to feed that to `write_string`. I though this made the code unnecessarily complex.

I decided to use instead a 3rd, user-invisible string. This is is easily achieveable thanks the zero-width-space (`\u200b`):

```
string_parts = [...]

count = len(string_parts)
if count > 2:
    wb.write_rich_string(row, col, *string_parts)
elif count == 2:
    string_parts = ['\u200b'] + string_parts
    wb.write_rich_string(row, col, *string_parts)
elif count == 1:
    wb.write_string(row, col, string_parts[0])
```